# Google analytics in chrome extension using ES6

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, ecmascript-6

I have made an extension where I added some analytics by following [analytics doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_analytics) so this worked fine when I didn't use ES6 but recently I converted my whole extension in ES6 and created class for extension but this doesn't work, even in network I can see that ga.js is getting loaded but pageviews or events are not registering also its not giving any error. Below is my class:

```
class GoogleAnalytics {
    constructor() {
        let _AnalyticsCode = 'xxxx-xxxxx';
        this._gaq = this._gaq || [];
        // Set or create account
        this._gaq.push(['_setAccount', _AnalyticsCode]);

        var ga = document.createElement('script'); 
        ga.type = 'text/javascript'; 
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        let self = this;
        $('#wrapper').on('click', '#foot_twitter, #foot_facebook, #foot_setting', function (event) {
            var thisEle = $(this).attr('id');

            // tracking event home is the category, clicked is the event & footer_<> is the label
            if(thisEle == 'foot_twitter') {
                self._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'home', 'footer_tw', 'clicked']);
            } else if(thisEle == 'foot_facebook') {
                self._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'home', 'footer_fb', 'clicked']);
            } else if(thisEle == 'foot_setting') {
                self._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'home', 'footer_setting', 'clicked']);
            }
        });
    }
}
export default (new GoogleAnalytics);
```

Comment: `(new GoogleAnalytics);` looks a bit weird. try `(new GoogleAnalytics());` to return a singleton. also try adding `console.log` or `debugger` into constructor to see if its being loaded correctly.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I would think the first thing would be to switch to analytics.js  and stop using ga.js

Comment: @DaImTo in google's doc it has been given this way if you want to use analytics in chrome extension, I think normal app analytics won't work here because of host. In extension host is  `chrome-extension:// `

Comment: ga.js is a legacy library.   I cant clam to be a chrome extension dev but I did google "universal analytics and chrome extension" quite a few articles were returned it appears to be possible to use analytics.js .   All Google analytics accounts were converted to universal analytics more then a year ago so you are trying to write to a universal analytics account using code that was intended for use with classic analytics.